# How can I call a subclass method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, subclass

How can I call a subclass method work() if this line needs to remain the same:

`Employee secretary = new Secretary();`

```
public class Employee {
}

public class Secretary extends Employee {
     public void work() {};
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Employee secretary = new Secretary();
     //secretary.work(); 
}
```

Comment: If you need to call the `work` method on an `Employee`, you'd better make sure that the `Employee` method has a `work` method. Currently you're no better off than just saying `Secretary secretary = new Secretary()`.

Comment: Feels like a homework question...

Comment: Your ``Secretary`` does not even extend ``Employee``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Secretary class must extends `Employee`

```
public static class Employee {
}

public static class Secretary extends Employee{
     public void work() {
     }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Employee secretary = new Secretary();
     ((Secretary)secretary).work(); 
}
```

And because `secretary`is declared as `Employee` you cannot invoke the methods of the `Secretary` class, you need to cast it :

```
((Secretary)secretary).work();
```

This will tell the compilator that your `secretary` is an `Employee` of type `Secretary` and then you will be able to call the `work()`method.

Answer (score 1):

What's the use of extending a class if the parent has to know of API methods? That defeats the concept of abstraction (which is implied in your need to call the method on a variable declared as the parent type)

It makes sense to declare the work() method in the parent, make the class abstract and implement it in the child.

```
public abstract class Employee {
    public abstract void work();
}

public class Secretary extends Employee {
    public void work() {
         //Implement here...
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee secretary = new Secretary();
    //secretary.work(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `Secretary extends Employee` means `Secretary` will have all public and protected things in `Employee` So, don't expect that you will get all things in object of type `Employee`.

you can do something like this

```
public abstract class Employee {
    public abstract void work();
}

public class Secretary extends Employee {
    public void work() {
         //Implement here...
    };
}
```

OR

```
interface Stuff{
    void work();
}

class Employee implements Stuff{

    @Override
    public void work() {

    }
}

class Secretary extends Employee {
     public void work() {}
}
```